# Multivariable chain rule with vector valued function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbf{g}:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. How do I find a formula for $\nabla (f \circ g)(x)$?

Answer (score 8):

Personally I find it easier to work in more generality (where we don't have this strange asymmetry between the scalar-valuedness of $f$ and the vector-valuedness of $g$, and so the situation is more analogous to the one-dimensional chain rule).

**First the general definition of the derivative of a function between higher-dimensional spaces**:

We say that a function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is *differentiable* at a point $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ if there exists a matrix $Df_\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ (called the *derivative* of $f$ at $\mathbf{x}$) such that
$$ \frac{f(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{x})-Df_\mathbf{x}\mathbf{h}}{|\mathbf{h}|} \to \mathbf{0} \hspace{5mm} \textrm{as } \mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}. $$
In this case, if we write $\,f_i \colon \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ (with $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$) for the $i$-th coordinate function of $f$, then for each $j \in \{1,\ldots,m\}$, the partial derivative $\,\partial_jf_i\,$ of $\,f_i\,$ in its $j$-th input exists at $\mathbf{x}$, and
$$ \boxed{(i,j)\textrm{-entry of } Df_\mathbf{x} \ = \ \partial_jf_i(\mathbf{x}).} $$
In the case that $f$ is scalar-valued, the derivative $Df_\mathbf{x}$ is simply a row vector, namely the transpose of $\nabla f$.

> > **Theorem.** *Suppose we have $g \colon \mathbb{R}^l \to \mathbb{R}^m$ and $f \colon \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $g$ is differentiable at a point $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^l$ and $f$ is differentiable at $g(\mathbf{x})$. Then $f \circ g$ is differentiable at $\mathbf{x}$, with*
> >     $$ \boxed{D(f \circ g)_\mathbf{x} \ = \ Df_{g(\mathbf{x})}Dg_\mathbf{x}} $$
> >     *Hence in particular, for each $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $j \in \{1,\ldots,l\}$, taking the $(i,j)$-entry of the LHS and the RHS gives*:
> >     \begin{align*}
> > &\left.\frac{\partial f_i(g(t_1,\ldots,t_l))}{t_j}\right|_{(t_1,\ldots,t_l)=\mathbf{x}} \\
> > & \hspace{5mm} = \ \sum_{r=1}^m \left( \left.\frac{\partial f_i(y_1,\ldots,y_m)}{y_r}\right|_{(y_1,\ldots,y_m)=g(\mathbf{x})} \right) \!\! \left( \left.\frac{\partial g_r(t_1,\ldots,t_l)}{t_j}\right|_{(t_1,\ldots,t_l)=\mathbf{x}} \right)
> > \end{align*}

Note how the boxed formula is the exact parallel of the one-dimensional chain rule:

$$ (f \circ g)'(x) \ = \ f'(g(x))g'(x). $$

The intuition behind this theorem is fairly straightforward: The increment $g(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h})-g(\mathbf{x})$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$ is approximately equal to $Dg_\mathbf{x}$ times the increment $\mathbf{h}$ in $\mathbb{R}^l$; and therefore the increment $f(g(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h}))-f(g(\mathbf{x}))$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is approximately equal to $Df_{g(\mathbf{x})}$ times the approximate increment $Dg_\mathbf{x}\mathbf{h}$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

In the case that $f$ is scalar-valued, expressing the formula using $\nabla$ notation gives

$$ \boxed{(\nabla(f \circ g))(\mathbf{x}) \ = \ (Dg_\mathbf{x})^T (\nabla f)(g(\mathbf{x}))} $$

(You can probably see why I find the "general version" more intuitive.) In other words,
\begin{align*}
& \textrm{$j$-th entry of } (\nabla(f \circ g))(\mathbf{x}) \ = \ \left.\frac{\partial f(g(t_1,\ldots,t_l))}{t_j}\right|_{(t_1,\ldots,t_l)=\mathbf{x}} \ = \\
& \hspace{8mm} \ \sum_{r=1}^m \left( \left.\frac{\partial f(y_1,\ldots,y_m)}{y_r}\right|_{(y_1,\ldots,y_m)=g(\mathbf{x})} \right) \!\! \left( \left.\frac{\partial g_r(t_1,\ldots,t_l)}{t_j}\right|_{(t_1,\ldots,t_l)=\mathbf{x}} \right)
\end{align*}

(In your case, you happen to have that $m$ and $l$ are the same number, namely what you have called $n$ in your question.)

---

*Proof of the Theorem.* [Throughout this proof, I work with the convenient convention that dividing a positive number by $0$ gives $\infty$; this prevents unnecessary splitting between the cases where $\mathbf{x}$ is and is not a stationary point of $g$ and $g(\mathbf{x})$ is and is not a stationary point of $f$.]

We need that for any $\varepsilon>0$, if $\mathbf{h} \in \mathbb{R}^l$ is sufficiently small then
$$ |\,\underbrace{f(g(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h}))-f(g(\mathbf{x}))-Df_{g(\mathbf{x})}Dg_\mathbf{x}\mathbf{h}}_{=:\,\mathcal{E}(\mathbf{h})}\,| \ \leq \ \varepsilon|\mathbf{h}|. $$
Define $\mathrm{Rem}_{g,\mathbf{x}} \colon \mathbb{R}^l \to \mathbb{R}^m$ by
$$ \hspace{-6mm} \mathrm{Rem}_{g,\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{h}) \ = \ g(\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h})-g(\mathbf{x})-Dg_\mathbf{x}\mathbf{h} $$
and likewise $\mathrm{Rem}_{f,g(\mathbf{x})} \colon \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ by
$$ \hspace{7mm} \mathrm{Rem}_{f,g(\mathbf{x})}(\mathbf{v})\ = \ f(g(\mathbf{x})+\mathbf{v})-f(g(\mathbf{x}))-Df_{g(\mathbf{x})}\mathbf{v}. $$
Then
$$ \mathcal{E}(\mathbf{h}) \ = \ Df_{g(\mathbf{x})}\mathrm{Rem}_{g,\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{h}) + \mathrm{Rem}_{f,g(\mathbf{x})}(Dg_\mathbf{x}\mathbf{h}+\mathrm{Rem}_{g,\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{h})) $$
for all $\mathbf{h} \in \mathbb{R}^l$. Now fix $\varepsilon>0$. Let $\delta_1>0$ be such that
$$ 0<|\mathbf{h}|<\delta_1 \ \Rightarrow \ |\mathrm{Rem}_{g,\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{h})| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2\|Df_{g(\mathbf{x})}\|}|\mathbf{h}|. $$
Let $\tilde{\delta}>0$ be such that
$$ |\mathbf{v}|<\tilde{\delta} \ \Rightarrow \ |\mathrm{Rem}_{f,g(\mathbf{x})}(\mathbf{v})| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2(\|Dg_\mathbf{x})\|+1)}|\mathbf{v}|. $$
Let $\delta_2=\frac{\tilde{\delta}}{2\|Dg_\mathbf{x}\|}$ and let $\delta_3>0$ be such that
$$ |\mathbf{h}|<\delta_3 \ \Rightarrow \ |\mathrm{Rem}_{g,\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{h})| \leq \min(|\mathbf{h}|,\tfrac{\tilde{\delta}}{2}). $$
Then setting $\delta:=\min(\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3)$, we have
$$ |\mathbf{h}|<\delta \ \Rightarrow \ |Df_{g(\mathbf{x})}\mathrm{Rem}_{g,\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{h}) + \mathrm{Rem}_{f,g(\mathbf{x})}(Dg_\mathbf{x}\mathbf{h}+\mathrm{Rem}_{g,\mathbf{x}}(\mathbf{h}))| \leq \varepsilon|\mathbf{h}| $$
as required. $\ \ \square$

Comment: I also like to think with matrices, maybe you can add the result in the sum version instead of just the product of the gradients? It would be helpful to see the equality (third squared formula).

Comment: Thank you for the good suggestion. I will do this.

Comment: See my answer where I follow that path!

Answer (score 3):

We have 
\begin{align*}
&f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
&\mathbf{y}\to f(\mathbf{y})=f(y_1,\ldots,y_n)\\
\\
&\mathbf{g}:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}\\
&\mathbf{x}\to \mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{g}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\\
&\qquad\qquad\,=(g_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n),\ldots,g_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n))\\
\end{align*}

> Recalling the *[nabla-operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del#Definition)* applied to $f$
>   \begin{align*}
> \nabla f(\mathbf{y})=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_1},\ldots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_n}\right)
> \end{align*}
>
> we  obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\nabla f(\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x}))}
> &=\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}f(\mathbf {g(\mathbf{x})})\right)_{1\leq j\leq n}\\
> &=\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j} f(\mathbf {g}(x_1,\ldots,x_n))\right)_{1\leq j\leq n}\\
> &=\left(\frac{\partial }{\partial x_j}f(g_1(x_1,\ldots,x_n),\ldots,g_n(x_1,\ldots,x_n))\right)_{1\leq j\leq n}\\
> &=\left(\frac{\partial  f}{\partial g_1}\cdot\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial x_j}+\cdots+
> \frac{\partial  f}{\partial g_n}\cdot\frac{\partial g_n}{\partial x_j}\right)_{1\leq j\leq n}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial g_k}\cdot\frac{\partial g_k}{\partial x_j}\right)_{1\leq j\leq n}}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you are given the Jacobian $(J)$ of $g,\,$
and the gradient $(h)$ of $f$
$$J = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \quad\implies dg = J\,dx \\
h = \frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \quad\implies df = h^Tdg$$
Then combining these two quantities yields the desired result
$$\eqalign{
df &= h^Tdg \\&= h^T(J\,dx) \\&= (J^Th)^Tdx \quad\implies
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= J^Th \\
}$$

Answer (score 0):

Everyone is giving the answer with proofs, but let me explain WHY the answer is what it is!

For a differentiable map $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R^m}$, I think of $Dh(x)=\nabla h(x)$ as a linear map that takes a vector $v$ (with its base at $x$) to the vector $Dh(x)(v) \in \mathbb{R}^m$ based at $h(x)$. This value in fact is equal to the partial derivative of $h$ at $x$ in direction $v$. When $Dh(x)$ is represented as a matrix, then $Dh(x)v$  is a matrix multiplication.

Now, you have the composition $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R^1}$. Fix an $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that gets mapped via $x \to g(x) \to (f\circ g)(x)$. If you take a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ based at $x$ then derivative of $g$ at $x$ sends it to the vector $w:=Dg(x)v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, a vector based at $y:=g(x)$. Now, what does $f$ do to it? It sends it to $Df(y)w $ therefore, the initial vector $v$ ended up as
$$ Df(g(x))\cdot(Dg(x)v) \ ,$$
read: derivative of $f$ at $g(x)$ applied to the vector $Dg(x)v$. Because $Dg(x)$ and $Df(g(x))$ are linear maps, this is the composition of, i.e. matrix multiplication of, the two, applied to $v$.

Comment: In my answer, I have attempted to explain "WHY the answer is what it is", in the short paragraph beginning "The intuition behind this theorem is fairly straightforward:...". I described it in terms of approximation of "increments" rather than in terms of "vectors based at a point"; but, of course, thinking in terms of vectors is just as good, if not better, **provided** one has an intuition for what these vectors mean.

Comment: You're right. That is another look at it. I am secretly talking tangent pace $T_x\mathbb{R}^n$ here.

Comment: Otherwise, without an intuition of what these vectors actually mean, there is *no reason* to believe that sequential application of the derivative $Dg$ of $g$ followed by the derivative $Df$ of $f$ gives the same result as applying the derivative $D(f \circ g)$ of the overall sequential application of the map $g$ followed by the map $f$ --- except perhaps some "Occam's razor" argument to the effect that the formula is the simplest well-defined general formula that one could attempt to write down for the multidimensional chain rule, and so it would be kinda nice if this formula also true.

Comment: As hinted at in your answer, if $v$ is a unit-length vector then $Dg(x)v$ can be thought of as the "partial derivative of $g$ along the direction of $v$". But more generally, "vectors based at $x$" correspond to *velocities* of a motion through the point $x$. So given $g \colon \mathbb{R}^l \to \mathbb{R}^m$ that is differentiable at $x \in \mathbb{R}^l$, if the motion of a particle $p(t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^l$ is mapped onto $\mathbb{R}^m$ by $g$, and if $p(t_0)=x$ and $p$ is differentiable at $t_0$, then setting $v=\dot{p}(t_0)$ we have that $t \mapsto g(p(t))$ has derivative $Dg(x)v$ at $t_0$.

Comment: This approach to thinking about vectors and derivatives then enables your argument to be convicing. *Or alternatively*, I still like to think of tangent vectors at $x$ as being the infinitely zoomed-in picture of infinitesimal displacements away from $x$.